# Android Studio gradle compilation error

Tags: gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I wonder if you can help, I'm not a very exerienced developer but trying my had at Android Development. I'm using Android Studio which uses gradle. I'm getting the following compilation error:

> Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':HelloWorld'.
>
> > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> >     Configuration with name 'default' not found.

My folder structure is:

```
HelloWorldProject
.HelloWorld
.libraries
..facebook
..build.gradle
.src
..main
..build.gradle
...java
....com.helloworld
.....firstPage
.gradle
..wrapper
...gradle-wrapper.jar
...gradle-wrapper.properties     
.build.gradle
.settings.gradle
.gradle.properties
```

my ./build.gradle in the root is empty

my ./setting.gradle file contains:

```
include ':libraries:facebook', ':HelloWorld'
```

my ./HelloWorld/build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

my ./HelloWorld/src/build.gradle contains:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been getting crazy in the last days with gradle related problems. I think that, if your project is not so big, you shall create a new project from the scratch, add your components throug the File -> new component menu, and have a running project in a few minutes. You will not understand wich is the problem, but in this early days of gradle an of android studio there are so many bugs and changes that is not worth to spend much time on such problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, in most cases, is a library doesn't have a build.gradle file.  In this case, it would be the facebook library.